# Create a React app with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: node.js, reactjs, intellij-idea

I am creating my first React app in IntelliJ IDEA by following [these instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/react.html). After following the New Project Wizard, I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/node /usr/local/bin/index.js untitled
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/usr/local/bin/index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:427:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:151:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:542:3
Done
```

Why is it looking in `/usr/local/bin/`? And where should it be looking instead? How do I configure IntelliJ to do this correctly?

P.S. I have an IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate license and installed the NodeJS plugin. I have NodeJS 7.10.1 and npm 5.4.2 installed. I also installed `create-react-app` with npm.

Note: I can run `create-react-app` (version 1.4.0) from the command line without any error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the New Project wizard, IntelliJ is asking for the folder where the create-react-app package is installed. I originally gave the location of the create-react-app binary executable. I solved this problem by pointing IntelliJ to `/usr/lib/node_modules/create-react-app`.